# Is it good practice to add primary keys to a tables during the alter statement, or it makes no deference to add them when I cam creating the table

Tags: mysql

I created/defined an admin table, now I have seen other programmers alter the table and add keys to the tables

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `admin_surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `phone` CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `admin_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `admin`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `admin_email` (`admin_email`);
```

If I have already defined the table why should I alter the definition again here?

Answer (score 0):

In InnoDB there exists clustered index always.

When primary key exists in a table then it is used as clustered index.

When no primary key but unique index(es) which's expression does not innclude NULLable columns exists then the most upper unique index from them in the table definition is clustered.

When no such unique index then inner hidden row number is used as an expression for clustered index.

Hence, if you create a table (and some expression is used for clustered index) and then use ALTER TABLE for to add primary key then the table must be rebuilt. It doesn't matter when the table is empty, but when there is data in it the process may be long enough (because COPY method is used).

If you create primary key as a part of CREATE TABLE then this is always fast.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put all the index definitions *inside* the `CREATE TABLE`, and put them at the end instead of sitting on the column definitions.

Potential problem 1:

But I notice that some dump utilities like to add the indexes later.  This may be a kludge to handle `FOREIGN KEY` definitions.  Those have trouble if the tables are not created in just the right order.

It would seem better to simply `ADD FOREIGN KEY...` after all the tables are created and indexed.

Potential problem 2:

If you will be inserting a huge number of rows, it is usually more efficient to make the *secondary* keys *after* loading the data.  This is more efficient than augmenting the indexes as it goes.  For small tables (under, say, a million rows), this is not a big deal.

I do not understand why they `ADD PRIMARY KEY` after loading the data.  That requires (as Akina points out) tossing the fabricated PK, sorting the data, and adding the real PK.  That seems like extra work, even for a huge table.

If the rows are sorted in PK order, the loading is more efficient.  The table is ordered by the PK (for InnoDB); inserting in that order is faster than jumping around.  (mysqldump will necessarily provide them in PK order, so it is usually a non-issue.)